# Entropy problem in addresses generated by Daedalus wallet

Tags: wallet, daedalus, address, private-key

I've created a new wallet in Daedalus, and I've noticed that 20 new generated addresses have the same repeating pattern in the second part of each address. Here's how it looks like:

```
addr1..............29995jus7mml099y23nh0q6ak33kgwtq7algrytcj45.............
addr1..............29995jus7mml099y23nh0q6ak33kgwtq7algrytcj45.............
addr1..............29995jus7mml099y23nh0q6ak33kgwtq7algrytcj45.............
```

*Is it a common practice for Daedalus wallet to generate addresses this way?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be the Payment address from your wallet. It is your stake key. All your Payment addresses will have the stake key which shows up in all receive addresses of the wallet. Its nothing to do with entropy in the Private Key which is generated using an opensource library.
It may be seen as a privacy issue to include the same staking key in all your addresses. But if you want privacy you can use cli to generate receiving addresses without the stake key.

Comment: Hi @raghu, thank you for your answer. Why are you calling these addresses `Payment`? Is there something special about them?

Comment: @Andy Fedoroff. There are several types in addresses in the Cardano ecosystem. The one used for sending and receiving payments are called Payment address. Reference https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet/